# display all number in msgbox from 2010 to 2015

Tags: excel, vba

how to display all numbers from-to. For example one value is 2010 another 2015 and I want to display in msgbox: 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tmpSO()

Dim lngNumber As Long
Dim txtMessage As String

For lngNumber = 2010 To 2015
    txtMessage = txtMessage & lngNumber & Chr(10)
Next lngNumber

MsgBox txtMessage

End Sub
```

Comment: works great! How to display the oposite way? 2015 2014 2013 2012 2011 2010. Thank you

Comment: Just remove the line `For lngNumber = 2010 To 2015` and write instead `For lngNumber = 2015 To 2010 Step - 1`.

Comment: Sorry by mistake I am new here :) Just accepted again